# In a multi-level meta-analysis, are moderator variables random or fixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I am conducting a multi-level, mixed-effects meta-analysis where effect sizes are clustered within studies. In the R package `metafor`, I specify my model like this:

```
rma.mv(data = df,
       yi = g ~ 1,
       V = varG,
       random = ~ 1 | studyID) %>%
  robust(cluster = df$studyID) #To calculate robust standard errors
```

My outcome vector is `g`, its variance is `varG`, and my intercept is a random variable clustered within `studyID`. When I add a moderator to this model, should that also be specified as a random effect? Or is it a fixed effect? So far I haven't found a way to specify a moderator as a random effect using `metafor`. Instead, this is what I use:

```
rma.mv(data = df,
       yi = g ~ 1 + mod, #This is the same as adding the `mods` argument
       V = varG,
       random = ~ 1 | studyID) %>%
  robust(cluster = df$studyID) #To calculate robust standard errors
```

**I would think that the moderator should be a random variable for the same reason that the intercept is; it depends on the cluster (study), and so if we treat it as fixed we will end up with non-independent residuals.** But I'm also new to both meta-analysis and fixed-/random-variables, so I could be approaching this totally wrong.

Comment: Why not try adding random = ~ mod | studyID and see if the sky falls in? There are vvarious examples of this sort of model on the metafor project pages https://metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses for instance.

Comment: I looked into that, but that seems to be a way to specify inner & outer grouping variables, not additional random variables - see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metafor/versions/2.4-0/topics/rma.mv, the paragraph starting "In addition or alternatively to specifying"

Comment: If you would like to add random slopes for a predictor, you can use `random = ~ mod | studyID, struct="GEN"` (this is currently undocumented, but works as intended).

Comment: Excellent, thank you!